# QuickSight "Geographical fields aren't supported in joins between data sources"

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, geospatial, amazon-quicksight

I've been trying to work around this issue for a couple of days by now without success so far.

Imagine you have these two dummy datasets

**dataset_1**

```
id,latitud,longitude
1,-0.023437,-0.070068
2,-0.069099,-0.069099
```

**dataset_2**

```
id,name
1,"site one" 
2,"site two"
```

and you want to JOIN them by `id`. This is very straightforward with the QuickSight dataset editor. The issue happens when you change the data type of `latitud` and `longitude` to their geospatial type, since the error shown in the title pops-up and won't let you save the dataset.

The weird thing is that the error suggests the fields `latitude` and/or `longitude` being used to make the JOIN instead of `id`.

Before contacting AWS for a possible bug have anyone had and solved this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end we contacted AWS support. It seems they have this feature in consideration but it's still not addressed. They suggested us a work-around though :

> 1. Change the datatype of the Geo-spatial field to string and perform the join
> 2. Once the join is successful, go back to the dataset page, click on the dataset and select "Use in a new Dataset" option
> 3. This will create a new child dataset for the main dataset
> 4. Here you can change the datatype back to Geo-spatial and save it

Have in mind that the option `Use in a new Dataset` is disabled if your dataset have `Row-level security` or if it exceeds 3 levels of JOIN (in which case you'd have to follow @darcoli's answer first)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation with quicksight. Can you do the join in custom sql and then add the fields as geographical coordinates in data preparation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had to do this + the solution from AWS support for it to work since I already had 3 levels of JOINs